# Prolog logic flow

Tags: prolog, logic

I'm completely new to Prolog and working on a homework assignment. My program is supposed to take two lists of equal length, and perform D = sqrt((X1-Y1)^2 + (X2-Y2)^2 + ... + (XN-YN)^2). I've written the code to get the correct answer, but it's not presenting it correctly. I think it may be a problem with the flow of the logic, since it seems like it's ending in an infinite loop. It's supposed to look like:

```
?- distance([1,2,3], [2,3,4], D).
D = 1.732051.
```

My code is giving me the correct result, but it prints it like:

```
?- distance([1,2,3],[2,3,4],D).
1.732051
true
```

And only because I have a line in there to print the result. It also does not end (no period) until I hit enter, which is why I fear I have a loop. How do I rephrase my code or redirect my logic, to get it to print normally?

```
distance([],[],D) :-
  F is sqrt(D),
  format("~f~n", [F]).

distance([A|T1], [B|T2], D) :-
  var(D),
  S is (A-B)*(A-B),
  distance(T1, T2, S);
  C is A-B,
  E is C*C,
  F is D+E,
  distance(T1, T2, F).
```

Comment: Shouldn't `F` evaluate to `D-E`, not `D+E`? You want the recursive distance to be the overall distance minus the distance from just the first terms each time. I am also confused by the line `distance(T1, T2, S);` can you perhaps comment on that?

Comment: N/M, I see what you are doing now.. accruing the sum of the distances in the last argument. I think that's a bit obfuscated, but correct. So the only issue is the weird printing. I think this is related to your lack of a true base case. In your method, distance([],[],0) won't be true. Also note how your code hangs when run, waiting for an extra '.' after returning true.

Answer (score 2):

Your program does not enter into an infinite loop, otherwise you would most likely get a stack overflow error at some point.
What´s happening is that your code leaves an open choicepoint so eventually the interpreter tries to redo (unsuccessfully).
You are not getting the result as expected because the variable D used in the calling procedure never gets bound.

You'd better solve this problem thinking how to model it recursively. In this case you could for example split the problem when the input lists are empty and when they are not (I am assumming here that calling your procedure with empty lists will yield 0 as a result).

So, in this scenario you would create two clauses, one for the base case (empty lists) and another for the recursive steps. I will also use a common approach used in prolog that consists of using an accumulator.

So we create a fact for distance/3 that will just call another procedure that uses this accumulator:

```
distance(L1,L2,F) :-
    distance(L1, L2, 0, F).
```

We use the accumulator to hold the partial result of the sum of squared item differences (A-B)*(A-B) in your code:

Now we start with the base case (empty lists):

```
distance([],[],S,F) :-
  F is sqrt(S).
```

Here we state that the result when no more items are left is the square root of the accumulator.

We now follow with the recursive step, the one which computes the squared item differences of the first item in each list and does recursion.

```
distance([A|T1], [B|T2], D, SQRT) :-
  S is D+(A-B)*(A-B),
  distance(T1, T2, S, SQRT).
```

Now we are done:

```
?- distance([1,2,3],[2,3,4],D).
D = 1.7320508075688772.
```

Comment: Of course! Thank you for explaining everything so clearly and concisely. I used the changes you gave me and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the use of the `format` function, so all I can do is provide my own attempt at this. I think your attempt has the drawback that it is not stated clearly in terms of base cases of the recursion.

Consider my approach below:

```
distance([],[],0).
distance([A],[A],0).
distance([A|T1],[B|T2],D) :-
    distance(T1,T2,F),
    D is sqrt((A-B)*(A-B) + F*F).
```

Comment: Note that you are computing another function. For example with list of 3 items you would be doing `(A1-B1)^2 + sqrt((A2-B2)^2 + sqrt((A3-B3)^2)^2)^2`. Also your second base case is not necessary.

Comment: Won't it be faster with the second base case than without? Perhaps also more numerically robust (though usually this isn't a problem in Prolog).

Comment: The problem is that it is less clear. If you'd want it to be faster and also more robust you probably should use an accumulator to allow for tail recursion (otherwise you might have stack issues)

Comment: Hmm, I had thought the benefit of my approach is that it is *more clear*, but you raise very good points. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use an accumulator :

```
distance(L1, L2, D) :- 
    distance(L1, L2, 0, D).

distance([], [], TT, D) :-
    D is sqrt(D).

distance([X1 | Y1], [X2 | Y2], TT, D) :-
    TT1 is TT + (X1 - X2) * X1 - X2),
    distance(Y1, Y2, TT1, D).
```